# Group by ( remarks ) Value in php mysql

Tags: php, html, mysql, group-by, html-table

Below is **products** table :

```
id | mid | wgh | remark| remkok | 
1    3     1.5    r3ok      1
2    2     1.5              0 
3    2     0.6    nice      0 
4    1     1.2    okh       0
5    4     1.5    bye       0
6    4     2.4    okby      0
7    3     3.0    oknice    1
```

I want to display remark  below  **tr** of group by mid..like below

```
    mid   wgh  
    3     1.5   
          3.0 
  remarks : r3ok, oknice
    4     1.5
          2.4
  remarks : bye, okby
    2     1.5
          0.6
  remarks :  , nice
    1     1.2
  remarks : okh
```

**What I have tried as below :**

```
$pid= null;
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{

 $rowpkts =  $row['mid'];
 echo "<tr class=\"undercl\">";
   if($rowpkts != $pid){
         echo'<td align="center" valign="top">'.$row["mid"].'</td>';
  }else{
        echo'<td align="center" valign="top"></td>';
   }

   echo'<td align="center" valign="top">'.$row["wgh"].'</td>';

  echo "</tr>";

// what i tried to build for remarks as below

$remsql = "SELECT mid as onu , GROUP_CONCAT(`remark` ORDER BY `id` ASC  SEPARATOR ', ') AS plrmks 
FROM products  WHERE 1=1 GROUP BY `mid`";
$fetchremk = mysql_query($remsql);
$rowresults =  mysql_fetch_array($fetchremk);

 if($rowresults['onu'] == $pid ){   

  echo"<tr style='border-style:underline;'>";
       echo'<td align="center" align="top">'.$rowresults["plrmks"].'</td>';               
           echo"</tr>";
        }
  }
  $pid = $rowpkts;
}
```

But remarks is not coming proper below **tr**... it means its not display below mid=3 or mid=1.

Any other way,that would help me.

Comment: any master here ....if any confusion with question please let me know will try to explain ...but any one please help me

Comment: Please make your question more specific and clean it up a bit. Also I see an error in code - extra apostrof char after word `WHERE`.

Comment: @jehy thanks for reply ... error code removed...might be copy-paste issue ... basically .. i want to display that remark below the group by mid value

Comment: hey i have made my question more simple now...please check

Answer (score 0):

Add appropriate colspan as required and do not do center align.

Try below code

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{

    $rowpkts =  $row['mid'];
    echo "<tr class=\"undercl\">";
    if($rowpkts != $pid){
         echo'<td align="center" valign="top">'.$row["mid"].'</td>';
    }else{
        echo'<td align="center" valign="top"></td>';
    }
    echo'<td align="center" valign="top">'.$row["wgh"].'</td>';

    echo '</tr>';
    $remsql = "SELECT mid as onu , GROUP_CONCAT(`remark` ORDER BY `id` ASC  SEPARATOR ', ') AS plrmks 
    FROM products  WHERE `remkok`= 1 GROUP BY  `mid`";
    $fetchremk = mysql_query($remsql);
    $rowresults =  mysql_fetch_array($fetchremk);

    if($rowresults['onu'] ==  $pid ){   

       echo"<tr><td colspan ='?'> Remarks : ";
       echo $rowresults["plrmks"];               
       echo "</td></tr>";
     }
    $pid = $rowpkts;
}
```

Comment: hey thanks for reply ,.... issue is not about colspan ....issue is that remark is not coming below ...tr ...